# How to change working directory in Python 2.7(Anaconda 4.0.1)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```py
import os
os.chdir('(Working directory which I want to set)')
```

changes the directory as expected. When I quit Python and start Python again, the directory is changed to original directory.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to write a program where you can do `python yourfile.py` and your directory is different afterwards? A program can't change its caller's working directory, so that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are typing commands directly into the interpreter. If so when you close the interpreter it dose not remember what you did in the last session. Try saving your code in a .py file. Gedit works well for editing .py files. After saving your file open the terminal and change directories to the location of your file. Then type to run your code.

```
python "your_file_name".py
```

replace your_file_name with the name of your file.

Also, to write code in a question indent the code four spaces.